# Science fair: "Can Lego's Fly"

Tags: technic

I am doing my science fair on "Can legos Fly!" I am going to build a glider and test it 3 times (Independent variable). the wings will be foam. I will test it on how far it flys (Dependent variable).

The point is if you have any suggestion I would love to hear them, but you better hurry, before I order the parts.

Comment: You can hurl LEGO across the room - unless that's not considered 'flying'

Comment: No... I'm looking for sustained flight.

Comment: and besides, that's what I;m doing for the control.

Comment: I have about 2 weeks before I order parts, so hurry!!

Comment: For inspiration, watch this: https://youtu.be/EwMBjKcY2Uc